# SQL Select based on pattern

Tags: query, select, like

I have a SQL column in my system that has a bunch of file names. I am attempting to separate the file names based upon a matching file name pattern. Some files have a middle initial and some dont. Example
219_21900004_TEST_PATIENT_P_8_15_1936.pdf
219_21900005_TEST_SECONDPATIENT_9_23_1936.pdf

I am looking for a SQL query where the file name is going to be
AnyNumbers_AnyNumbers_AnyLetters_AnyLetters_AnyNumber_Wildcard

Trying to just write something where I can identify if the 5th ordinal position (using underscore as separator) is a number or a letter. This will help me identify if there is a middle initial. Any help appreciated